# Disable categorization in "method / event / enum dropdown browser"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, customization

### [image]

.

In VB6, the dropdown in the IDE shown above wasn't categorized.
I could easily browse "ucBoardGrid"'s events and properties as they were all shown in the same dropdown menu.

While VS2017 tries to organize things for me, I feel that it's mostly much more time-taking to browse where I want to:

First I need to select the "main category" in the left dropdown menu, then I can view the methods / events / properties in the right dropdown menu.

Is there a way to disable this categorization? I would like everything to be shown in a single dropdown list right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fondly remember the old VB6 menu's just as you've explained.

> I would like everything to be shown in a single dropdown list right away.

I doubt you can remove the categorization, however I have something far more amazing. These days I find myself using `Ctrl+T`.

The new **Go to All window** in Visual Studio 2017 lets you navigate directly to any file, type, member, line or symbol by typing a search query:

[image]

The main difference from the Navigate To window (existed since Visual Studio 2010) is that now you can easily limit search results to files, types, members or symbols clicking on the corresponding toolbar button. Alternatively, you can type the special character and space before the search query:

[image]

Works for Files (f), Types (t), Members (m), Symbols (#) and Lines (:),  e.g. `f stac` for file paths containing stac

[image]

**Edit:** Apart from `Ctrl+T`, I typically use `F12` to goto definition. Then I use `Ctrl+ minus key` to go back, and back, `F12` forward, *and back, again*. It's the fastest I've found.

I'm also a fan while debugging to pull up `Ctrl+Alt+c` the call stack, up/down arrow keys while focus is on CallStack window.

F12 & Ctrl+**-** is the key, anything else `Ctrl+T`.